# Why does the reflected light have a specific direction?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, geometric-optics

If a light incident on a smooth surface ,then light reflects. Why does the reflected light goes in a direction such that angle of incidence and angle of reflection  to be equal and reflected ray be in the plane of incidence? 
In short , why does the law of reflection hold true?

(I mean the plane of incidence here as the plane containing the incident ray and perpendicular to the surface of incidence)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/451874/why-is-angle-of-incidence-equal-to-angle-of-reflection).

Comment: Thanks. But why there should be a single plane containing the reflected ray? Why doesn't reflected ray go not in the plane of incidence such that angle of reflection and angle of incidence equal?

Comment: @MIDHUNMURALITVM The fact that it is contained in the same plane is because of conservation of momentum.